# Finding the dimension of the set of all linear maps mapping $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces. Let $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$. What are the possibilities for the dimension of the subspace $$\{T \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,W) : T(v_1) = 0, T(v_2) = 0, T(v_3) = 0 \}?$$

Comment: Depends. Are the OPs guesses of $nm - m$, $nm - 2m$, and $nm-3m$ correct as the three possibilities? Depending not the linear dependence of the three vectors.

Comment: Well, in fact there are four posibilities: if $j = \dim(\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\})$ (so $j \in \{0,1,2,3\}$) then the dimension is $nm-jm$.